# print function shifts the output result

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, metrics

I don't know if it is explicit in the title but i want to print a `classification_report`.

I want to write that it belongs to the `Test set` just like this :

```
print(f'Test classification report :{classification_report(y_test, y_pred)}')
```

But it gives this output with the 4 column names shifted :

```
Test classification report :              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.68      0.50      0.57       187
           1       0.79      0.89      0.84       407

    accuracy                           0.77       594
   macro avg       0.74      0.69      0.71       594
weighted avg       0.76      0.77      0.76       594
```

Thanks

Comment: `print(f'Test classification report :\nclassification_report(y_test, y_pred)}')` - note the `\n` - would print the heading on a new line. Is that what you want?

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` is the way to go
It adds a new line